# Which @controller annotation should I be using with Spring-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
org.springframework.stereotype;
```

or

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc;
```

I had been using the stereotype but just noticed I have another option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
```

Is an annotation.  It indicates that the annotated class is a controller as well as a candidate for auto-detection (like a @Component).  This is the annotation you want to use.

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller
```

Is an interface for implementing controllers.  In most simple cases you probably don't want to be using this.